# Trying to make a triangular Java Multiplucation Table

Tags: java

I am trying to make a "triangular" multiplication table. It must have 15 rows and 10 columns, no duplicates. Must be using loops. I am having a hard time trying to figure this one out. I am left with extra columns. Please help!

[Here is what it is supposed to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcXR8.png)

```
public class q2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

         final int jMax = 15; 
         final int iMax = 10;

         System.out.println("");
         System.out.print("  |  ");

          for (int column = 1; column <= iMax; column++)

             System.out.print(column + "\t"); 

          System.out.println();


          System.out.print("____________________________________________________________________________");

          System.out.println();

          for (int i = 1; i <= jMax; i++)
          {       
              if (i>9)
              {
             System.out.print(i + " | ");
              }
              else
                  System.out.print(i + "  | ");

             for (int row = 1; row <=i; row++) {

                System.out.print(i*row + "  ");
             } 
             System.out.println();

          } 
       }

}
```

Comment: What does it do now?

Comment: perfect, works now thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The reason you have extra columns is this line here:

```
for (int row = 1; row <=i; row++) {
    System.out.print(i*row + "  ");
}
```

This will make you print out one more column for each iteration of the for-loop outside of it, which goes up to 15. (`for (int i = 1; i <= jMax; i++)`) To fix this, you can use ternary operators, which are essentially an if-statement in a single line. If you instead make the for-loop's condition
`row <=(i < 10 ? i :10)`, then you will fix your issue of printing out a new column each iteration. In the for-loop, it looks like this:

```
for (int row = 1; row <= (i < 10 ? i :10); row++) {
    System.out.print(i*row + "  ");
}
```

You might still have issues with formatting, but this solves your issue with the rows.